# How to highlight text of a PDF within Evernote?

Tags: pdf, evernote

Is there a way to easily highlight text of a PDF in Evernote on Windows?
I'm using the Windows desktop EN program. Would be great if the method also worked on the web version.

So far all I've gotten to work is the Evenote pdf annotator. This is very awkward to use for this purpose.

Use Case:
Reading a pdf document and highlighting important ssesctions.

Comment: Since this is (largely) about the desktop version, it belongs here rather than WebApps, IMO.